# Blazor InputNumber decimal format

Tags: decimal, rounding, blazor-server-side

Ideally I would like to apply `Math.Round()` method to my Blazor's `InputNumber` in order to remove the .xx from a decimal value.

```
 <InputNumber class="someClass" @bind-Value="@DcValue"></InputNumber>
```

Please note the model's DcValue is decimal and will have to stay decimal.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: If this is purely for viewing purposes, why can't it just be an `<input type="number"`? with a step and have it disabled?

Comment: James... Apologies it needs to be editable. Is there any way the rounding can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom control to manage that requirement. [More details here](https://www.meziantou.net/bind-an-inputnumber-on-input-with-decimal-numbers-in-blazor.htm).